# Pip with broken connection: "connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out."

Tags: python-3.x, pip, openssl, ipv6, timeoutexception

I'm trying to install a package (any package) with pip on Ubuntu 18.04 as well as Ubuntu 20.04. However, I end up with the following error message:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pip/
...
```

This is what I tried and what didn't work:

- increasing the timeout
- changing proxy and/or index server
- reinstalling all of python
- reinstalling openssl (plus messing around with it)
- thinking that the host server was on some blacklist at my service provider up to opening and explicitly allowing ports 443 and 80 with ufw
- upgrading the OS (from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04) up to reinstalling the whole OS.
- Installing Anaconda

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I eventually scanned through this one below, that although it's for Windows it actually worked on Ubuntu linux too!!

> [Pip ReadTimeoutError in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461613/pip-readtimeouterror-in-windows-10/63177333#63177333)

and the way to fix it is then simply disable ipv6 with the following commands, and done!

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```